# Can we assign Array to the key of Record and Object in index of Tuples in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, tuples, record, ecma

ES15 has introduced Records and Tuples, So can we use array as a attribute value inside the Record? Can we use object as a value of Tuple index?

#### 1. Is it a valid for Record ?

```
const user = #{
  name: "Avyukt",
  age: 39,
  hobbies: ['sleeping', 'eating', 'crying'] // Is it a valid add arr 
}
```

#### 2. Is it a valid Tuple?

```
const user = #[ 
    { name: "Avyukt", age: 1 }, // Is it valid to add object as a value
    { name: 'Reyansh', age: 5 } 
]
```

Comment: If you delete the `#` symbols, that looks like valid javascript to me. Did you run into any issues with it?

Comment: Tuples and Record are introduced in ES15, using # symbol we can convert object to Record and array to Tuples. Currently it is not supported by browser. @NicholasTower

Comment: You can learn more about Record and Tuples here

https://medium.com/@opensrc0/es15-ecma-script-2024-5b316636b8ca

Comment: Still a proposal, so probably refer to the official [proposal documentation](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple?tab=readme-ov-file#examples) now?

Comment: You are right @AdamJenkins, it is a proposal of es15 and might be introduced with ES15 release. Thanks for the official doc link.

Comment: @Pointy Above given Record and Tuple are valid? As in the record I have assign an arr to the key of Record and assigned an object value to the Tuple.

Comment: Well it's right there in the spec, and the answer is **no**.  Values in tuples and records must be primitives.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the proposed specification:

https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple/blob/5c9a6e144c687ef5911f4c0c088bc21343cbaf68/README.md?plain=1#L252

> Records and Tuples may only contain primitives and other Records and Tuples. Attempting to create a Record or Tuple that contains an Object (null is not an object) or a Function throws a TypeError.

No, a tuple may not contain an object, but it can contain a Record, in the current proposal

Likewise, a record may not contain an array value, but it can contain a tuple.

I would caution against the title that ES15 has introduced anything.

This is currently a stage 2 proposal only.

Answer (score 0):

As Adam pointed out in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78014926/5648954), in the current iteration of the proposed spec you can't store objects (including arrays) in records or tuples, otherwise you'll get a TypeError. The escape hatch the spec authors [suggest](https://tc39.es/proposal-record-tuple/tutorial/index.html) is the use of a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) with a Map. The idea is to place a Symbol in the place of your object/array within your record/tuple. The `Symbol` is then used as a key in a Map, allowing you to essentially dereference the symbol by looking up its corresponding value in the Map, for example:

```js
const RefsRegistry = new WeakMap(); 
const hobbiesRef = Symbol("hobbies");

RefsRegistry.set(hobbiesRef, ['sleeping', 'eating', 'crying']); // ECMAScript 2023 (ES14) now allows for Symbols in WeakMaps

const user = #{
  name: "Avyukt",
  age: 39,
  hobbies: hobbiesRef
};
```

Now the above record is valid, since it no longer contains an array, but rather holds a Symbol, and as that's a primitive it's allowed.

When reading the value, you would need to dereference the Symbol using the Map, for example:

```js
const hobbies = RefsRegistry.get(user.hobbies);
```

Comment: As if the proposal itself isnt odd enough. If you don’t want *deep immutability*, then you don’t actually want to use these proposed data structures to begin with. The fact that there’s a “managing state” section in this proposal blows my mind. These specs should be for broadly used/needed language features

Comment: @AdamJenkins The contributors to this proposal seem to think there are cases for doing so (check out the discussions here [#31](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple/issues/31) & here [#200](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-record-tuple/issues/200) (they're quite lengthy)).